# Can't clone anything in Git

Tags: git, github

I've been using git with GitHub for a while, and recently cannot clone, push, or do anything with it. Since github provided a very vague error (and told me to check my internet connection, even though it can fetch available repos fine, and my internet is working), so I went into git to investigate

```
C:\Users\vkoves\Documents\GitHub>git version
git version 1.8.4.msysgit.0

C:\Users\vkoves\Documents\GitHub>git clone https://github.com/vkoves/TheSpeedOfT
imeBuild.git
Cloning into 'TheSpeedOfTimeBuild'...
error: Unable to create C:/Users/vkoves/Documents/GitHub/TheSpeedOfTimeBuild/.gi
t/HEAD
```

I've done a lot of research into the issue, and have found nothing that's worked. I've uninstalled and reinstalled github a zillion times, which hasn't helped either.

So how can I fix my problem?

Comment: Have you checked space? Permissions?

Comment: I agree with @klm123 - sounds like a permissions issue.

Comment: There's enough space on the hard drive, and can you tell me exactly how to check the permissions?

Comment: Did you completely delete the local folder `TheSpeedOfTimeBuild` and all its subfolders between attempts?

Comment: Can you create the file `C:/Users/vkoves/Documents/GitHub/TheSpeedOfTimeBuild/.git/HEAD` using another program (such as Notepad)? It doesn't look like GitHub has anything to do with this error.

Comment: Yes, though I had to use command line to create the .git folder, and then used echo "" > HEAD to make an empty HEAD file

Comment: But that doesn't really help, since it won't clone to a folder if it has anything in it.

Comment: And @Jud, yes, I completely deleted the folder between attempts.